# Angular async data

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous

i'm trying to get data from my api, the code for getting datas :

```
getList() {
    this.fileList = [];

    this._globalService.getUserFiles(this.userId)
      .then(files => {
        files.forEach(retFile => {
          this._globalService.getFileActions(retFile._id)
            .then(retActions => {
              this.fileList.push( {
                file: retFile,
                action: retActions
              });
            });
        });
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.finish = true;
      });
  }
```

Call OnInit hook. 
After, my view is trying to show same that :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="finish; else wait">
      <ng-container *ngIf="fileList.length; else noItems">
        <li *ngFor="let item of fileList">
         ...
        </li>
      <ng-container>
      <ng-template #noItems>
        <span class="noItems">Any file</span>
      </ng-template>
<ng-container>
```

That works fine. 
But my problem lasts a few seconds the #noItems template is to show when datas exists, like in this example :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You always push your result into this.FileList, you this.FileList never empty, therefore your noItem template never show up.

Comment: The array is emptied at init with this line : this.fileList = [];

Comment: The problem it's: when array is not empty (like my gif example) the #noItems template is show, his should not